# How to "link" PRs in different repos from an automatic flow?

Tags: github, github-actions

The context is: I have two repos `A` and `B`. I have set up a Github action that runs on repo `A`'s PRs: it invokes a workflow in repo `B` that opens another PR with a few changes related to repo `A`'s changes. I want to link both PRs in some way, so the person that opened the PR in repo `A` can **automatically** go to the corresponding PR in `B`, maybe through a link.

What I have tried:

- I propagate `A`'s PR number through the workflow and automatically post a comment in `B`'s PR with a link in the form `<org>/<repo>#<PR-number>`. Additionally, the commit with the changes and the PR's description also contain the same link. I'm using [add-pr-comment](https://github.com/mshick/add-pr-comment/) to post the comment. The issue is that, unlike normal comments by users, this doesn't produce a "this PR was mentioned here" comment in `A`'s PR.

To recapitulate:

- A PR in `A` produces a PR in `B`. I want someone in `A` to be able to see which PR in `B` was produced. Whether this is through a comment in `A`, or through a comment in `B` that creates a reference in `A`, that doesn't matter.
- I tried through a comment in `B` that triggers a reference in `A`. This doesn't seem to work, and maybe it has something to do with automatic vs user comments.

Is there a known way to do this?

Comment: When informing a PR url from a repository on another repository, doesn't GitHub automatically create a reference on each PR from one repository to the other? (alongside comments and commits data)

Comment: no, I have seen this working if the comment is done manually. It will appear as: user x referenced this PR in ... . But, when done through a comment using add-pr-comment it doesn't show up at all. I tried with exactly the same text in both cases.

Comment: Thanks for the extra context. Do you use a PAT with a specific permission scope in your automation? It could be related to that.

Comment: I'm not using PATs, but instead a Github App token. Using PATs is not an option for us for security reasons.

Comment: Some endpoints on Github API don't work with GitHub App user access tokens, GitHub App installation access tokens, or fine-grained personal access tokens. I don't know if the behavior you're experiencing might be related to that. Just a curiosity: Could you share the security reasons regarding the PAT usage you're referring to?

Comment: Mainly, I think we want to limit exposure in case a former employee looses their PAT.

Comment: If that's the case, I would suggest creating an Organization User (that wouldn't be associated to any employee, but to the whole organization), and create a PAT for this "service user" with a specific scope, that could be shared among all the organization repositories as Organization secret (it requires a bit of governance and processes, but enables other advantages).